# Files.copy renaming files

Tags: java

Was hoping you could look at some code for me:

```
public void Copy(Path sourcepath,
        Path targetpath) throws IOException {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd");


    File origfile = targetpath.toFile(); // Changes targetpath to file
    String name = origfile.getName(); // Gets the name of the file to be updated
    File file1 = new File(targetpath.toString() + "." + dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())); //Create a new file instance with the name of the old file + date
    origfile.renameTo(file1); //Rename the original file
    origfile.createNewFile(); //Backup the original file
    Files.delete(targetpath); //Delete the original file
    Files.copy(sourcepath, targetpath);
}
```

Now everything works, the backing up works and the copying works. My original intention was to rename file being copied to the file being backed up. (hence the string name = origfile.getName();

This was my code:

```
File file2 = new File(name);
File srcfile = sourcepath.toFile();
srcfile.renameTo(file2);
```

Now, that worked up to a point, after a while I started getting IOException errors, so after a few hours of struggling. I gave up and just deleted that renaming part.

Lo and behold it still renames the file when being copied.

Now my question: Does Files.copy do it? Is there some mysterious thing happening here? It does EXACTLY what I want it to do, but I am baffled as hell. Why is my code working?

and yes I want to know, in case it breaks or stops working. I can't have something work and not know why!

EDIT:

Sorry was in a bit of a rush when posting, let me pose my question a bit more clearer:

my intention was to have my sourcepath renamed to the original name of the file that is being backed up. I had code to rename it, but it threw an IOException so I deleted it. I only used Files.Copy, so I assumed sourcepath would retain it's original value, and just copy for each instance in a for loop I have. But no, it renames perfectly to the original of each file being backed up. Where and how?

Comment: I'm not clear on what the question is.

Comment: I want to know why my files are being renamed when there is no code to specify them to do so. i.e. why is sourcepath's file being renamed when it is being copied (it is doing what I want it to do, I want it to be renamed, but my renaming code didn't work so I deleted it)

Comment: ... Copying a file doesn't do any "renaming", it copies a source file to a target file. You pass in a source and a target. You copy the source to the target. You rename the original file and do a createNewFile. I'm still not clear on where the confusion is.

Comment: Sorry, let me try to explain it step by step.

Comment: No, that's okay. Step through your code, and see what it actually does, perhaps referring to the Javadocs.

Comment: Yeah.. It's like said above. Do you mean the your source files are disappearing after the copy? Btw, the IOexception was probably due to the fact that the target file already existed.. You can override that of course though.

Comment: my code is for (int i = 0; i < targetdir.length; ++i) then for every selected file in the target directory, my file gets copied over. (an updater of sorts). Now you would expect that for each time it get's copied over, it retains it's original name, no? Test.txt? Well, I have three files, test1.txt,test2.txt,test3.txt, and my code above backs them up and renames them to the current date, after which my file is copied over. Now my file copies and each time renames itself to test1.txt,test2.txt and test3.txt. Exactly what I want it to do, but I never wrote any code for it to do so.

Comment: My source file isn't disappearing, it's renaming itself each time it's copied over. I like that, I LOVE that. But I never wrote that!

Comment: I have a JFrame GUI along with it, two selectors with jfilechooser to select srcfile and targetfiles(array). I just tried it again. Created a test.txt(sourcefile) and test1.txt, tester.txt and ran it. test1.txt and tester.txt got backed up and had the date added to them. Test.txt got copied over twice and renamed to test1.txt and tester.txt respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Wooo!

Because I converted the targetpath to a file, backed it up and *deleted it* this happened:

when I used Files.copy(srcpath,targetpath) srcpath took targetpath's name (the file is deleted but the original path is still there because nothing happened to it)

So basically: two paths were sent to my method, my method created a backup file and deleted the original file (not the path) of the original path. (which would be c:\work\testorigfile e.g.)

Thus when I used Files.copy(srcpath,targetpath) it worked exactly as I wanted it. The answer WAS in the javadoc (in a sense) so thanks for all the tips guys!